# Basic Java Echo Socket Communication Error

Tags: java, sockets

I have been looking through the multitudes of explanation of basic Java Socket use, and have constructed the following basic code for my own Server/Client echo pair. However, there is some hangup in the client code that I cannot find for the life of me. Perhaps someone else can spot it?

```
    // Server Code:
    try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(22222);
                Socket cSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(cSocket.getOutputStream());
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                     new InputStreamReader(cSocket.getInputStream()))) {
        System.out.println("Client connected: " + cSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
        // console DOES print ^this line and correct IP when client is run.
        String inLine;
        while (true) {
                inLine = in.readLine();
                out.println(inLine);
                if (inLine.equals("exit")) break;
        }

    // client code
    try (Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 22222);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader consoleIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));) {
    String userIn;
    while (true) {
            System.out.print("Client> ");
        userIn = consoleIn.readLine();
        out.println(userIn); // code hangs here. 
        out.flush();
        System.out.println("Server> " + in.readLine());
        if (userIn.equals("exit")) break;
    }
```

Comment: It shouldn't block there. Are you sure it isn't hanging at the line before, reading the console? Have you forgotten to enter some input into the client? NB you need to check the result of `readLine()` for null, at both ends.

Comment: The code hangs after I enter some input, and then press enter. The prompt goes to a blank line and refuses input in the Client console. This would be the expected behavior if it was either failing to send or recieve the message from the server, but I don't know which for sure.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bzmbe59bsWNmcXpjY0VSclkwWVk&usp=sharing
is the link to the files if you want to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't blocking there. It's blocking in the `readLine()` from the server. Try a `flush()` after the `println()` in the server.

Comment: Yep! That got it. Thanks. I didn't think the `flush()` was necessary, but I added it as an afterthought in the Client.

Comment: Wouldn't it cause an error AFTER the first attempt rather than ON the first attempt if flush was the problem? Just seeking a little clarity.

Comment: No, why? It's necessary if you don't construct the `PrintWriter` with autoflush, which you did in the client, and not in the server. You had a redundant flush in the client and a missing `flush()` in the server, or a missing autoflush.